# Input the score in database

Tags: android, database

I need a most secure database and also a simple score saving into database for one or two months have a simple game which i want that score to goes into database (with name) and no one can see it. I don't know much about databases so i need your help. I know its small description but i don't know what to write else.
Thanks.
**EDITED**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickSound.start();
            String value = seconds.getText().toString();
            if (value.equals("End!")) {
                clicks.setText("Total Clicks: " + countClicks);
            } else {
                clicks.setText("Clicks: " + countClicks++);
            }
        }
    });
    new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            seconds.setText("Seconds: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            seconds.setText("End!");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: What you have done yet comeup with some code Thanks!

Comment: Actually i'm scared to show the code and idea because of stealing.
Ok, anyway just a simple clickable game ...

Comment: Don't ask anything!!! you are scared of stealing and want some one for legal stealing why some one should help you he should let you give the right to steal their idea

Comment: there is the code i need that score to go into database. (simple)
Ok my bad for saying that ...

Comment: Ok anyone to help please ? There is the code i have just a simple clicking game ... :/

Comment: There is no database related code here... What have you tried with regard to that?

Comment: like i said i have no knowledge with databases so i need help to make it that happen.

Comment: Please anyone to show me just a how to start a simple database to save the score .. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get started with SQLite Database [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html). If you know basic SQL, then this would be easy. This tutorial is very straight forward and easy to learn.

Come back again if you have problems regarding SQLite.